# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) - Segmentation fault: 11 - Crash occurring on zoom plugin - macOS - Swift - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, plugins, zoom-sdk

---

I'm working on an application with virtual camera plugin for macOS by using swiftUI & swift. It has also C++ & objective C library. When we use that plugin via zoom crash is happening randomly.

What's the main reason of this crash. I made several changes on my code but didn't get rid of this crash. Is there anybody who can explain?

Crash report is provided below.

```
Process:               caphost [10599]
Path:                  /Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/caphost.app/Contents/MacOS/caphost
Identifier:            us.zoom.caphost
Version:               5.12.2.11434 (5.12.2.11434)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zoom.us [10598]
Responsible:           zoom.us [10598]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-12-27 09:55:57.914 +0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H15)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        DE314E93-14D7-0DBB-EB56-80C3DE2D2BA3

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4658FDDE-8271-48E3-972C-A6F2EA766607

Time Awake Since Boot: 130000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        11  Dispatch queue: IBYLightVideoOutputQueue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [10599]

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000106f4a000-0000000106f5e000 [   80K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/caphost.app/Contents/MacOS/caphost

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d0dfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d1170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305daef5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305d99c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305d8e3e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2f205abd RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2f2057d5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 584
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2f205579 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d84b039 _DPSNextEvent + 883
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d849880 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d83b58e -[NSApplication run] + 658
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d80d396 NSApplicationMain + 777
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6a68fcc9 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d3882 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894425 _pthread_cond_wait + 698
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff67962592 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
3   us.zoom.caphost                 0x0000000106f519bb 0x106f4a000 + 31163
4   us.zoom.caphost                 0x0000000106f51ae7 0x106f4a000 + 31463
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d0dfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d1170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305daef5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305d99c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305d8e3e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d9ec954 _NSEventThread + 132
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 3:: AMCP Logging Spool
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d0e36 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff64263b16 caulk::mach::semaphore::wait() + 16
2   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff642639b2 caulk::semaphore::timed_wait(double) + 106
3   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff642637c4 caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::run() + 30
4   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff642631e4 void caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, void (caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::)(), std::__1::tuple<caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread*> > >(void*) + 45
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d0e36 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff64263b16 caulk::mach::semaphore::wait() + 16
2   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff642639b2 caulk::semaphore::timed_wait(double) + 106
3   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff642637c4 caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::run() + 30
4   com.apple.audio.caulk           0x00007fff642631e4 void caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, void (caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::)(), std::__1::tuple<caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread*> > >(void*) + 45
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d3756 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6a756eea nanosleep + 196
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6a756de4 usleep + 53
3   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff3187bb03 CMIOGraph::OneOrMoreInputUnitsAreReadyToBePulled(bool&) + 635
4   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff3187c565 CMIOGraph::DoWork(unsigned int) + 413
5   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff3187eda7 CMIO::Thread::QueuedTWorkThread<unsigned int>::DoWork() + 123
6   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff31886458 CMIO::Thread::SignaledThread::ThreadLoop() + 144
7   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff318863b3 CMIO::Thread::SignaledThread::WorkQueuedThreadCallback(void*) + 53
8   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff317965c3 figThreadMain + 276
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d3756 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6a756eea nanosleep + 196
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6a756de4 usleep + 53
3   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff3187bb03 CMIOGraph::OneOrMoreInputUnitsAreReadyToBePulled(bool&) + 635
4   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff3187c565 CMIOGraph::DoWork(unsigned int) + 413
5   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff3187eda7 CMIO::Thread::QueuedTWorkThread<unsigned int>::DoWork() + 123
6   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff31886458 CMIO::Thread::SignaledThread::ThreadLoop() + 144
7   com.apple.CoreMediaIO           0x00007fff318863b3 CMIO::Thread::SignaledThread::WorkQueuedThreadCallback(void*) + 53
8   com.apple.CoreMedia             0x00007fff317965c3 figThreadMain + 276
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d0dfa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d1170 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305daef5 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 247
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305d99c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1319
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff305d8e3e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 462
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff30661489 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   com.apple.cmio.DAL.AppleCamera  0x000000010a74fde8 0x10a744000 + 48616
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a894109 _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb8b thread_start + 15

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: cpatureVideoOutput
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a7d0e36 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a636aed _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a636fbf _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 98
3   us.zoom.caphost                 0x0000000106f59799 0x106f4a000 + 63385
4   us.zoom.caphost                 0x0000000106f59efb 0x106f4a000 + 65275
5   us.zoom.caphost                 0x0000000106f54681 0x106f4a000 + 42625
6   us.zoom.caphost                 0x0000000106f54240 0x106f4a000 + 41536
7   saasbee.nydus                   0x000000010ac36ed8 0x10ab34000 + 1060568
8   saasbee.nydus                   0x000000010ac36f09 0x10ab34000 + 1060617
9   saasbee.nydus                   0x000000010ac36992 0x10ab34000 + 1059218
10  saasbee.nydus                   0x000000010ac36a8f 0x10ab34000 + 1059471
11  saasbee.nydus                   0x000000010ab81d76 0x10ab34000 + 318838
12  saasbee.nydus                   0x000000010ac0e558 0x10ab34000 + 894296
13  com.apple.avfoundation          0x00007fff2bf2593e _49-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput render:sampleBuffer:]_block_invoke + 228
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a6356c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a636658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a63bc44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a63c5d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a645c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a890a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IBYLightVideoOutputQueue
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff694da6e8 objc_retain + 24
1   com.bjit.ibycameralight.plugin  0x000000010ad88a7e Stream.sendInformation(information:with:) + 1694
2   com.bjit.ibycameralight.plugin  0x000000010ad8a7fc Stream.videoCapture(_:didCapture:with:) + 4444
3   com.bjit.ibycameralight.plugin  0x000000010ad8c305 @objc Stream.videoCapture(_:didCapture:with:) + 229
4   com.bjit.ibycameralight.plugin  0x000000010adf4ac0 IBYVideoProcessor.captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:) + 1584 (IBYVideoProcessor.swift:179)
5   com.bjit.ibycameralight.plugin  0x000000010adf4b86 @objc IBYVideoProcessor.captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:) + 118
6   com.apple.avfoundation          0x00007fff2bf2593e _49-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput render:sampleBuffer:]_block_invoke + 228
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a6356c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a636658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a63bc44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a63c5d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a645c09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a890a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a88fb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000007530  rcx: 0x00007fc5688edfa0  rdx: 0x0000000000000020
  rdi: 0x00007fc5688edfa0  rsi: 0x0000700004686978  rbp: 0x0000700004686d10  rsp: 0x0000700004686998
   r8: 0x0000000000000026   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fff87f7f588  r11: 0x00007fff305accaf
  r12: 0x00000000ef9c8ef5  r13: 0x00007fc566e73bd0  r14: 0x0000000000000003  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff694da6e8  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000020
  
Logical CPU:     3
Error Code:      0x00000004 (no mapping for user data read)
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x106f4a000 -        0x106f5dff7 +us.zoom.caphost (5.12.2.11434 - 5.12.2.11434) <EA3CD1FC-35F1-3FDA-AC6F-F0150FCC1E0D> /Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/caphost.app/Contents/MacOS/caphost
       0x107cba000 -        0x107de6fff  com.apple.CMIOBaseUnits (1000.0 - 5125.6) <B685062C-F5C8-3500-885A-D3F401073D7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Resources/BaseUnits/CMIOBaseUnits.bundle/Contents/MacOS/CMIOBaseUnits
       0x107e0a000 -        0x107ec5ff7  com.apple.CMIOUnits (1000.0 - 5125.6) <D4A1043D-BB0E-3B89-8E61-74252C2D109F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Resources/CMIOUnits.bundle/Contents/MacOS/CMIOUnits
       0x10833c000 -        0x10833f047  libobjc-trampolines.dylib (787.1) <88F9B648-C455-36F8-BBB9-7D1A9F57D073> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x10847d000 -        0x108493ff7  com.apple.security.csparser (3.0 - 59306.140.5) <E47642C0-0664-3A22-B481-9E3D7DEC5573> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/PlugIns/csparser.bundle/Contents/MacOS/csparser
       0x1084ff000 -        0x108503fff  com.apple.audio.AppleHDAHALPlugIn (283.15 - 283.15) <AB88E450-7A43-3F72-9A07-FA761BA1B389> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn
       0x108531000 -        0x1085c2f47  dyld (750.6) <1D318D60-C9B0-3511-BE9C-82AFD2EF930D> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x10a6d4000 -        0x10a6f7ff7 +com.manycam.ManyCam.VideoDevice.plugin (8.0.0.45 - 8.0.0.45) <03F79F74-6AA2-3B67-86A6-8DBEADA83737> /Library/CoreMediaIO/*/ManyCamVideoDeviceCMIO.plugin/Contents/MacOS/ManyCamVideoDeviceCMIO
       0x10a71c000 -        0x10a72bff3 +com.obsproject.obs-mac-virtualcam.dal-plugin (27.2.4 - 27.2.4) <01B5429B-518F-3849-AE33-3720A3B28C12> /Library/CoreMediaIO/*/obs-mac-virtualcam.plugin/Contents/MacOS/obs-mac-virtualcam
       0x10a744000 -        0x10a761fff  com.apple.cmio.DAL.AppleCamera (400.7.6 - AppleCameraDeviceAbstractionLayer-7.6.0) <9FE4033E-4D59-31AF-8259-FEB651EED294> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Resources/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AppleCamera
       0x10ab34000 -        0x10acd7fff +saasbee.nydus (5.12.2 [11434] - 5.12.2.11434) <406A678A-B06C-3C9C-916B-ECF24E7BE111> /Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/nydus.framework/Versions/A/nydus
       0x10ad34000 -        0x10afdffff +com.bjit.ibycameralight.plugin (1.2.0 - 0.0.7) <680C73C6-2F53-3C4F-9960-F6A63F28D50D> /Library/CoreMediaIO/*/IBYVirtualCameraLightPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IBYVirtualCameraLightPlugin
       0x10b4f0000 -        0x10ba84fcf  com.apple.audio.codecs.Components (7.0 - 7.0) <64B6FB55-1A5A-3F1D-ACE6-A570671CC767> /System/Library/Components/AudioCodecs.component/Contents/MacOS/AudioCodecs
    0x7fff23649000 -     0x7fff23896ff8  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (9.02.0 - 1350.29) <59F81722-039E-33F5-A20E-936E997575A3> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff28f57000 -     0x7fff29356ff1  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver (14.7.8 - 14.0.7) <1FA5C980-0AFA-35AB-B904-8B41B75FB347> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver
    0x7fff2bdf6000 -     0x7fff2bff1ff8  com.apple.avfoundation (2.0 - 1855.3) <0837D912-3783-35D6-A94A-E474E18600CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
    0x7fff2bff2000 -     0x7fff2c0beffe  com.apple.audio.AVFAudio (1.0 - 415.75) <CAC3CA5F-FCF6-37EB-8F1A-090340E2C38E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/Versions/A/AVFAudio
    0x7fff2c1de000 -     0x7fff2c1defff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <4F9977AE-DBDB-3A16-A536-AC1F9938DCDD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff2c1df000 -     0x7fff2c1f5fef  libCGInterfaces.dylib (524.2.1) <8FD09D09-BB19-36C5-ADE9-4F22DA235AEE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
    0x7fff2c1f6000 -     0x7fff2c84cfff  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 524.2.1) <EA6F5FF2-7A1B-35D5-A5A3-D2B3386ECB75> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff2c84d000 -     0x7fff2cab4ff7  libBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <C6C2D42F-7456-3DBF-8BE2-9AA06EFC78FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff2cab5000 -     0x7fff2cf88fef  libBNNS.dylib (144.100.2) <99C61C48-B14C-3DA6-8C31-6BF72DA0A3A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff2cf89000 -     0x7fff2d324fff  libLAPACK.dylib (1303.60.1) <5E3E3867-50C3-3E6A-9A2E-007CE77A4641> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff2d325000 -     0x7fff2d33afec  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1303.60.1) <3D433800-0099-33E0-8C81-15F83247B2C9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff2d33b000 -     0x7fff2d340ff3  libQuadrature.dylib (7) <371F36A7-B12F-363E-8955-F24F7C2048F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff2d341000 -     0x7fff2d3b1fff  libSparse.dylib (103) <B8A10D0C-4577-343D-B310-A3E81265D107> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff2d3b2000 -     0x7fff2d3c4fef  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <B147FEF6-A0DB-3830-BF06-45BEC58DB576> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff2d3c5000 -     0x7fff2d59cfd7  libvDSP.dylib (735.140.1) <D63DC0A5-B8B4-3562-A574-E73BC3B57407> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff2d59d000 -     0x7fff2d65ffef  libvMisc.dylib (735.140.1) <3601FDE3-B142-398D-987D-8151A51F0A96> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff2d660000 -     0x7fff2d660fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <F6C5613D-2284-342B-9160-9731F78B4DE5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff2d661000 -     0x7fff2d6c0ff0  com.apple.Accounts (113 - 113) <E2438070-30AB-3B89-AE63-1E485B92D108> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Versions/A/Accounts
    0x7fff2d80a000 -     0x7fff2e5caff2  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1894.60.100) <A64D10A6-FE17-39CE-9392-6615BE54E10E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff2e61a000 -     0x7fff2e61afff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 50) <C23D2740-FAF6-3BD6-9E48-56F54D752864> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff2e61b000 -     0x7fff2e686fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (377 - 493.0.4.1) <87EA5DE1-506A-39FD-88BE-D8A3416C9012> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff2e71f000 -     0x7fff2e75dff0  libFontRegistry.dylib (274.0.5.1) <F3461C05-0370-359B-9F03-5C1C1F7763EC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff2e7b8000 -     0x7fff2e7e7fff  com.apple.ATSUI (1.0 - 1) <5F513967-DDD7-3F22-AD14-8A38ABD9F2D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATSUI.framework/Versions/A/ATSUI
    0x7fff2e7e8000 -     0x7fff2e7ecffb  com.apple.ColorSyncLegacy (4.13.0 - 1) <72EE68DB-F069-37F5-AA2A-40D5FCF139F4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSyncLegacy.framework/Versions/A/ColorSyncLegacy
    0x7fff2e886000 -     0x7fff2e8ddffa  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 676) <14DF4D42-E24D-3EBD-9A9D-93124D8D6AA1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff2e8de000 -     0x7fff2e8ecfff  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <01B8B6B3-E2C3-3607-B34A-8283A7E0E924> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff2e8ed000 -     0x7fff2e932ffa  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (15.4 - 516.2) <437BCF12-48D2-3770-8BC9-567718FB1BCA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff2e933000 -     0x7fff2e93dff7  com.apple.QD (4.0 - 413) <27A36D07-B5E9-32E6-87B6-3127F260F48D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff2e93e000 -     0x7fff2e94bffc  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (9.0.24 - 9.0.24) <75344F8F-32CA-3558-B4E6-F56D498250E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff2e94c000 -     0x7fff2ea2dffa  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <8CFA0620-5E43-3C4D-A75B-981C0961C2DE> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff2ea2f000 -     0x7fff2ea2ffff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.14 - 1.14) <C8F9CC56-F7CF-3E77-B6FC-BD8E1D19FA92> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff2edc6000 -     0x7fff2f155ffa  com.apple.CFNetwork (1128.0.1 - 1128.0.1) <07F9CA9C-B954-3EA0-A710-3122BFF9F057> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff2f1d1000 -     0x7fff2f1d1fff  com.apple.Carbon (160 - 162) <97E334B3-7FAE-3239-9E89-5A546BC26ADE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff2f1d2000 -     0x7fff2f1d5ff3  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.6 - 101) <9F6E13D9-374B-386F-8E15-FDD6CE967859> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff2f1d6000 -     0x7fff2f4caff3  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 994.6) <EAF2DAC3-66B1-30BF-AF10-72DDA90D1044> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff2f4cb000 -     0x7fff2f4ceff3  com.apple.help (1.3.8 - 71) <36483951-6F3E-3F7E-8A5B-191C2357EF17> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff2f4cf000 -     0x7fff2f4d4ff7  com.apple.ImageCapture (9.0 - 1600.65) <1A1F320E-3E85-3F3D-8AE0-B238C4E92D40> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fff2f4d5000 -     0x7fff2f4d5fff  com.apple.ink.framework (10.15 - 227) <284507AE-EF47-3ABC-86A4-669243DB1D33> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff2f4d6000 -     0x7fff2f4f0ffa  com.apple.openscripting (1.7 - 185.1) <B6E28747-5FC7-3461-8A71-864A969ED022> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
    0x7fff2f511000 -     0x7fff2f511fff  com.apple.print.framework.Print (15 - 271) <0D9FB08F-EA87-3BE7-821B-C61BA5601050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
    0x7fff2f512000 -     0x7fff2f514ff7  com.apple.securityhi (9.0 - 55008) <390C6FAA-99BF-3924-9180-9EAE41D9C6BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff2f515000 -     0x7fff2f51bfff  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (6.0.3 - 6.0.3) <9614A01E-8303-3422-A3BA-6CE27540E09A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff2f51c000 -     0x7fff2f6b4ffa  com.apple.cloudkit.CloudKit (867 - 867) <1B851180-FC00-357F-B6C1-BB0EA7D6D5CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/Versions/A/CloudKit
    0x7fff2f6b5000 -     0x7fff2f6b5fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 23) <2192EE61-8CA8-3639-B7D3-0D68F200C9EF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff2f6c3000 -     0x7fff2f7b9fff  com.apple.ColorSync (4.13.0 - 3394.9) <A126406C-DA38-3FFE-8B25-BB9859EFD159> /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff2f7ba000 -     0x7fff2f8aaff7  com.apple.combine (1.0 - 134.102) <02C5D48A-E70F-3D68-8555-4211853F9C3B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Combine.framework/Versions/A/Combine
    0x7fff2f8ab000 -     0x7fff2f9e4ff6  com.apple.contacts (1.0 - 3455.18) <57696192-BF9D-3946-8C78-35FCEF406B00> /System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework/Versions/A/Contacts
    0x7fff
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid address at 0x20 almost always means a NULL pointer to an object or struct was dereferenced and a member at offset 32 bytes was accessed.

The crash is in Stream.sendInformation(information:with:) in a call to [object retain]. Typically it is safe to retain a nil ptr in objc, so I’d probably be looking carefully at whether swift is making any guarantees about nullability here that might be circumventing that. I don’t use swift much, and can’t say I’m sure whether the objc nil safety arises out of objc_retain or more likely objc_msg_send first.  Anyway, running the thing in the debugger will probably shed some light on what is going on. You might also address any warnings in your build about places where you ignored nullability requirements, or perhaps you set something nullable in your own interface and failed to live up to the requirement.